# variable value available in scriptlet but not in jsp and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, scriptlet

I have this code.

```
<% String d = (String) request.getAttribute("testDate");%>
```

I print this variable and is printing from scriptlet. But when I try to access this variable in JavaScript

```
var date = "<%=d %>"; alert('Test '+date)
```

This is alerting 'Test null'. Also when I try to assign the variable to a hidden tag's value, it is taking as null.

```
<input type='hidden" name="testDate" value='<%=(String) request.getAttribute("testDate")%>' />
```

It is assigning null value to the input field. Also tried this

```
<input type='hidden" name="testDate" value='<%=d %>' />
```

It is assigning null value to the field.

Comment: Have you heard about JSTL?  `<input type='hidden" name="testDate" value='${testDate}' />`

Comment: Using a customized framework in my project, and there is no JSTL. Thank you.